# Proof of theorem egregium with moving frames

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

I'm learning the moving frame approach (with differential form) in surface theory from different books and papers (Cartan, O'Neill, Shifrin, Flanders and others).

Briefly: you define an adapted moving frame on the surface $(P, e_1, e_2, e_3)$, then you define the dual forms $\omega_i = dP\cdot e_i$ and the connection forms $\omega_{ij} = de_i \cdot e_j$. From Cartan's structure equations you find Gauss and Codazzi equations and other things. Next you prove the fundamental formula $d\omega_{12} = -Kd\sigma$ (where $K = detS$ is the gaussian curvature). Here in some texts follows two steps before arrive at theorem egregium:

1) You prove that if you consider another frame $(P, \bar e_1, \bar e_2, \bar e_3$) than $d\omega_{12} = d \bar \omega_{12}$

2) You prove that $\omega_{12}$ is the only 1-form which satisfy the two equations $d\omega_1 = -\omega_2 \wedge \omega_{12}$ and $d\omega_2 = \omega_1 \wedge \omega_{12}$ and so it is *intrinsic*

Are these steps necessary? I mean

1) It is not obvious that $d\omega_{12}$ does not depend on the frame since neither $K$ nor $d\sigma$ depend on the frame?

2) It is not obvious that $\omega_{12}$ is intrinsic since it's defined as $de_1\cdot e_2$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The point is to give an independent treatment, as you're going to use the equation $d\omega_{12}=-K\,d\sigma$ to *define* Gaussian curvature.  Now, what precisely do you mean by *intrinsic*?

Comment: For example, in Cartan K is defined as the determinant of II fundamental form. Then he shows that K depends only by the point on the surface and not by the frame. Is not also the same in your paper on this, when you derive $\omega_{13} \wedge \omega_{23} = KdA$? I know the other approach, where you define K using the fact that the space of 2-forms have dimension 1, but I'm following the classic (extrinsic) construction of K. For "intrinsic" I mean "that depends only on $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$". Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, we can use the extrinsic definition of $K$ (as the determinant of the shape operator), but then to infer the Theorema Egregium — i.e., that $K$ is *intrinsic*, i.e., dependent only on the induced metric and not on the particular embedding — we need to know that $d\omega_{12}$ is intrinsic. Note that the answer to your second question is no, as that dot product depends on the embedding of the surface in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: But $\cdot e_2$ doesn't say something like "you consider only the projection on the surface, you can measure it by living on the surface"?

Comment: That's not good enough. "Intrinsic" information should depend only on the induced metric, not on the way the surface is embedded.

Comment: The problem is that $de_1$ is not contained in the tangent space?

Comment: Well, $de_1$ is an $\Bbb R^3$-valued $1$-form, and you're interested in its tangential component, as you said. But depending on the position of the tangent plane is depending on the embedding in $\Bbb R^3$. Remember that "intrinsic" should mean that you can figure it out just knowing the induced Riemannian metric and not knowing how the surface sits in $\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: But even if you don't consider _all_ $de_1$? I mean: $e_1$ varies in all $\mathbb{R}^3$, and from the surface I don't know how it varies in the $e_3$ direction (so for example I cannot compute $\omega_{13}$ and $\omega_{23})$ but I can measure with the metric induced how it varies in $e_2$ direction. Where I am wrong? (sorry but I don't know anything about riemannian geometry)